# Does cfdocument or cfsavecontent have a size limit?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm building a pdf file via:

```
    <cfsavecontent variable="html_output">
    ...
    </cfsavecontent>

  
   <cfdocument format="PDF" orientation="landscape">
      #html_output#
   </cfdocument>
```

And it works fine, but if I try to fetch too much data, I get something like this on the page output instead of a pdf:

> %PDF-1.4 %���� 5 0 obj <>stream x���YoG�Ѓ>�+���±�x#�=�
> O����:,��(Od��
> ����U5G�H5d�aB"Mq��u|���*�9���,]�Y�|��������O��������Y�ʇ{|������Y��k�/_ë~�e���O?��_b�^�˪��eM�>�L�
> |P���/�!8��Ú���a�G����Z�/�e�|�+h�Of�b���z��=IӼ0����=M���iR$���I����E�~�Ln���%�o^t�\��kxn����;�����ʻoT���Uվ��yr�@�?��p���%��s��������b��^r����7�u�u{S������)�G��GE�X��}�p��w����U��7p{����Zѣ���_���~��
> .j�j���25ܯLZ./_�K�i0���|Y�������x��K���I٘���@Tf��T�5�����td@������*�*����}�I��Б��W�`�^J�^t7)1��Ր�Y���H�)5:���lU�G����ErizC��j���p��t
> 9���2~��:�);1�@�K��q�IH��uY
> @:�|L�)D�c�B1W���F1�;���u�����&!�� I�U+�1hq�
> VR��H�K�#�!Yg��&1%+�I�@����(W%?��:�60������벏��8�͇7��U�����%��uև�6��઎�v�|Jl0(�L�
> ��

Coldfusion's documentation doesn't list a size limit for either cfsavecontent or cfdocument. Am I hitting a size limitation, or there potentially some other issue?

EDIT: By printing directly to cfdocument, it does work. This indicates a cfsavecontent size limit. But that doesn't answer the question. What is that limit, and can I circumvent it?

Comment: `<cfsavecontent>` just writes a string to a variable. It's fundamentally the same as `<cfset>` except easier to do multi-line strings and allows for other operations to be inlined. So the limit there will be the limit of your heap size. This would be dead easy for you to test for yourself though: write a long string to it. Check it. Did it all go in? NB: you don't actually tell us how long the string data you're working with is, which is pretty key to "is this too big?". If it's large, I'd perhaps write the data to file and use `<cfhtmltopdf>` for this, instead of `<cfdocument>`.

Comment: @AdamCameron Saying it's the same as cfset adds some clarification, but it doesn't answer my question, because I can't find any documented information about a size limit for a cfset in coldfusion, either. The size of the string I was working with is irrelevant if  there's a way to know what the limit is. Regardless, I couldn't find a clear breakoff, because it accepted one string at around 200,000,000 characters but not another with 50,000,000 or so more.  Aside: `cfhtmltopdf` is too buggy to use.

Comment: You are looking for the wrong thing.   Both `<cfset>` and '<cfsavecontent>` produce variables so you should be looking at variable size limits.  Plus, I'm not sure that `<cfcontent>` produces only string variables.  What happens if you include an image?

Comment: @DanBracuk That actually makes sense. I looked at the documentation for the variables instead of `cfsavecontent` and it says "Strings can be any length, limited by the amount of available memory on the ColdFusion server" However, I find this hard to believe, as the resulting pdf from using `cfdocument` instead of `cfsavecontent` creates a pdf that is only 6.2mb

Comment: > "it doesn't answer my question, because I can't find any documented information about a size limit for a cfset in coldfusion, either" Well I did say "So the limit there will be the limit of your heap size", which is the answer to your question. Thinking there is a max setting for `<cfset>` or `<cfsavecontent>` doesn't make any sense. It's the length of the *value* that matters, not the mechanism you use to store it. And that limit is the size of a String, which is only limited by available heap space.

Comment: Seems to me (based on what you've said) that the issue is not the length of the string here, it's something *in* the string that CF is not handling the conversion to PDF. This is why I suggested `<cfhtmltopdf>` as it's *way* more reliably than `<cfdocument>`. Still: one can only lead the horse to water. To troubleshoot this, build a PDF that breaks, then use a binary chop kind of approach to narrow down the bit that it's not liking. You are gonna need to troubleshoot this one yerself, I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you saved the CFSAVECONTENT to a static HTML file on disk for review? (Also, are you outputting "valid" HTML 4.01 & CSS1 or 2 code?)  Once saved locally, are you able to fetch the static HTML file using CFDocument's "SRC" attribute or using CFINCLUDE? Regarding PDF generation, have you compared it with WKHTMLTOPDF? (We started using WKHTMLTOPDF as an alternative to CFDocument when CF8 was supported and we continue to prefer it.)

Comment: Sorry, I think a lot of the responses are not responding to something I added to my post. If I don't use `CFSAVECONTENT` and instead wrap the html in `CFDOCUMENT`, it does generate a pdf correctly. So the issue isn't character sets, invalid html, and so forth.

Comment: Does CFDocument generate a lot of unnecessary whitespace? Are you able to offload the CFContent content to a variable as it's being generated? I have a CF project that uses CFContent to create content for the PDF, but the HTML fragments are dumped into an array (or ordered struct) so that I can generate a HTML preview (w/navigation to jump between sections), save to disk or output using CFDocument/CFSection.